# Make jquery owl carousel dots work with function

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have downloaded all files to use jQuery Owl Carousel. It works great but when I'm trying to make a function of it in WordPress it don't show anything at all.

I'm very new at this so maybe I'm doing it completely wrong.

I'm just trying the way I did with my other functions but they are only in html/php.

Pls help a student :)

```js
  $('.slideshow_container').owlCarousel({
     loop:true,
     margin:10,
     nav:true,
     responsive:{
         0:{
             items:1
         },
         600:{
             items:1
         },
         1000:{
             items:1
         }
     }
 });
```

```css
.wrapper { height: 699px; /* owerflow: hidden */; background: #04fbc7;  margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px;
 
}

.item {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
function carousel_wiever () {
?>

<div class="wrapper">
 
 <?php  
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'citat',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
   );
   query_posts( $args );
   // The Loop
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
     
     <div class="text1">
        <span class="quote"><?php meta('citatet'); ?></span>
       </div>
     <div class="text2">
        <span class="author"><?php meta('citerat_av'); ?></span>
       </div>
       </div> <!-- item -->
       </div> <!-- owl-carousel  --> 
         </div> <!-- wrapper -->
         
      
   <?php endwhile;
   // Reset Query
   wp_reset_query();   
   ?>

       

<?php 
 
}
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a owl-carousel class inside your while loop. owl-carousel class should go to your wrapper instead

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
     loop:true,
     margin:10,
     nav:true,
     responsive:{
         0:{
             items:1
         },
         600:{
             items:1
         },
         1000:{
             items:1
         }
     }
 });
```

```css
.wrapper { height: 699px; /* owerflow: hidden */; background: #04fbc7;  margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px;
 
}

.item {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
function carousel_wiever () {
?>

<div class="wrapper owl-carousel owl-theme">
 
 <?php  
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'citat',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
   );
   query_posts( $args );
   // The Loop
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="item">
    <div class="custom_class">
     
     <div class="text1">
        <span class="quote"><?php meta('citatet'); ?></span>
       </div>
     <div class="text2">
        <span class="author"><?php meta('citerat_av'); ?></span>
       </div>
       </div> <!-- custom_class -->
       </div> <!-- item  --> 
         </div> <!-- wrapper -->
         
      
   <?php endwhile;
   // Reset Query
   wp_reset_query();   
   ?>

       

<?php 
 
}
```